# Postgres: how to check if a select statement returns an entry which exists and is not NULL

Tags: postgresql

I have a `select` in an `insert`. I want to check, if the `select` statement returns a value which is not NULL and the value exists.

```
insert into table (t1, t2) 
values ( (select param1 from table2 where row1=1 and row2=1), 1)
```

I tried a combination of `select EXISTS` and `nullif(a, '') is not null`, which did not work as expected.

In the following example, I want to have a FALSE when selecting b=5 (NULL) and b=6 (is not existing row).

`select EXISTS` returns true, even when a NULL entry exists.

What is the proper way for checking both conditions and putting it into the insert statement?

Example:

```
WITH test_data (a, b) as (
  SELECT * 
  FROM (VALUES 
         ('example1', 1), 
         ('2', 2), 
         ('example3', NULL), 
         ('example3', 3), 
         (NULL, NULL), 
         (NULL, 5), 
         (NULL, 5),
         ('example4', NULL)
       ) t
)
select EXISTS(SELECT a FROM test_data WHERE b=5) ;
--select a, nullif(a, '') is not null from test_data where b = 5;
```

Comment: select EXISTS(SELECT a FROM test_data WHERE b=5 and a IS NOT NULL)?